# A tag with plus signs in its name was created for an old, inactive question

Tags: bug, tags

This morning I saw this:

[image]

The red arrow wasn't there, I drew it.

This tag has only one question with no activity since December, so I'm guessing it was created by the system overnight. I have no idea why though.

[image]

I could even add a tag wiki excerpt. Cool.

[image]

So, is this a bug, or a new feature? Can we create info pages for tag combinations now?

Comment: So it's finally possible to create [c]+[c++]+[c#]?

Comment: [old bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164079) back in place https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67976273/vba-search-by-textbox-entry  ... it can celebrate a 12 year anniversary

Comment: @JeanneDark: No, because that would be undefined behavior ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao maybe Kevin did a final commit to reverse all the bugs he ever fixed and then closed the door behind him, never to be seen again ...

Comment: @rene probably that's why he still [has a ninja diamond](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeIQS.png).

Comment: Ha! So MSE got a "new" mod then ;)

Comment: Maybe Community did it. It could be sneaking around the offices at night. After all we know Community is not a robot.